# Rails 4 Rspec undefined method `patch'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Делаю "свой" проект, с оглядкой на http://railstutorial.ru/

При запуске тестов встречаю такую ошибку:

```
1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller submitting to the update action 
 Failure/Error: before { patch user_path(user) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `patch' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Authentication::Authorization::ForNonSignedInUsers::InTheUsersController::SubmittingToTheUpdateAction:0x000000046ee408>
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:63:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Мой spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
      require 'spec_helper'

  describe "Authentication" do

    subject { page }

    describe "signin page" do
      before { visit signin_path }

      it { should have_content('Sign in') }
      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
    end

    describe "signin" do
      before { visit signin_path }

      describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Sign in" }

        it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }

        describe "after visiting another page" do
          before { click_link "Home" }
          it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
        end
      end

      describe "with valid information" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before do
          fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
        it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
        it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }

        describe "followed by signout" do
          before { click_link "Sign out" }
          it { should have_link('Sign in') }
        end
      end
    end

    describe "authorization" do

      describe "for non-signed-in users" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        describe "in the Users controller" do

          describe "visiting the edit page" do
            before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
            it { should have_title('Sign in') }
          end

          describe "submitting to the update action" do
            before { patch user_path(user) }
            specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

utilities.rb:

```
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Callboard"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end

  def sign_in(user, options={})
    if options[:no_capybara]
      # Sign in when not using Capybara.
      remember_token = User.new_remember_token
      cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
      user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    else
      visit signin_path
      fill_in "Email",           with: user.email
      fill_in "Password",        with: user.password
      click_button "Sign in"
    end
  end
```

Gemfile :

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'validates_timeliness'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
# Покрытие тестами
gem 'simplecov', :require => false, :group => :test
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end




group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
end



group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

routes.rb:

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :users
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    root  'static_pages#home'
    match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
    match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
    match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
    match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
    match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
  end
```

Ссылка на остальной код https://bitbucket.org/Tiazar/callboard

Comment: @NickVolynkin в этом и вопрос. Почему не объявлен. Он определён в Rails.

Comment: это базовый метод в rails 4 http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/26/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/    , отсюда мое недоумение, где искать ошибку.

Comment: В общем случае нужный функционал включается строкой 'config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers' в spec_helper.rb , но у меня это почему-то не срабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За опознание типа теста отвечает строчка, помещаемая обычно в `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
```

Пример есть, например, [в исходниках Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb#L38), а [у вас такой нет](https://bitbucket.org/Tiazar/callboard/src/733d5addd4edcddfc01dcfb2ad0fbc4ac840fd0b/spec/spec_helper.rb?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Это нововведение RSpec 3.x: [теперь по умолчанию угадывание типа теста выключено](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#file-type-inference-disabled), чтобы не сбивать с толку новичков. А в ранних версиях такое поведение было по умолчанию. Туториал, видимо, требовал жёсткого указания версий, и такой проблемы не возникло.

Comment: Спасибо это действительно помогло. Railstutorial требует конкретные версии, порой довольно старые, поэтому я сознательно использовал последние, чтобы наткнуться на все нововведения пока учусь.

Answer (score 1):

Раз не сработал навык перевода сообщений об ошибке, воспользуюсь навыком перевода англоязычного SO.

`get`, `put`, `patch`, и другие методы определены только для спеков `:controller` и `:request` но не для `:feature` к которому неявным образом начинает относиться ваш тест `authentication_pages_spec.rb`, когда вы меняете его расположение. Если включить `type: :request` в `describe` верхнего уровня, должно заработать.

Там, кстати, даже упоминается, что эта ошибка встречается в Rails Tutorial Chapter 9 (`spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb`).

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18290271/2790048

Comment: К сожалению мой спек изначально в spec/requests/ , а не в spec/feature/( у меня вообще такой директории нет)

Comment: Сработало после того, как изменил соответствующий код на "describe "authorization", type: :request do ...", осталось понять почему так, ибо перед этим я делал другой проект полностью как в туториале и такой проблемы не встретил.